# How to check the size of a RxJS Observable object?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

My Observable contains a number of Observables like this:

```
const observables = of(0, 1, 5, 10).pipe(map(
      n => {
        return of(n).pipe(startWith(0)).pipe(delay(n * 1000))
      } // emit 0 and then emit n after n seconds
    ));
```

How can I check what is the size of an `observables` object?

The `observables` is an an `Observable<Observable<number>>` and in this case I know it contains 4 `Observable<Observable<number>>` each one containing two `Observable<number>` objects as printed by this little test:

```
let v1Counter = 0;  
      observables.subscribe(v1 => {  
        {  
          console.info("value v1:" + v1 + " v1Counter:" + v1Counter++ + " 'Observable<number>' type")  
          let v2Counter = 0;  
          v1.subscribe((v2) => {  
            console.info("value v2:" + v2 + " v2Counter"+v2Counter++ +" 'number' type")  
         })  
        }  
      });
```

Comment: In your particular case the observable will always give the same amount of values, but that is not true for all observables. So there is no way to tell how "big" an observable is in general.

Comment: @ShamPooSham. It must be cold as if I re-subscribe I am getting same output

Comment: there is a workaround you can make if your observables are executed **sequently** using [RxJS concat](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat) combined with a **counter**, but this will calculate the number of observed actions in runtime not before the execution of the observable. Except that you can not because Observables are NOT ARRAYS

Comment: @ShamPooSham. You know what is strange. I have added to my `observables` the `.pipe(share())` and when I re-subscribe it still prints the original content. I thought the share() will make it hot. This is my new code:  `const observables = of(0, 1, 5, 10).pipe(map(
          n => {
            return of(n).pipe(startWith(0)).pipe(delay(n * 1000))/*.pipe(startWith(0))*/
          } 
        )).pipe(share());`